# Unable to Set PDF text colour with Itextsharp and c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to set text colour of PDF using Itextsharp and c#.

Below is the snippet.

iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(sourcefilePath);
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader sReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(overlayfilePath);

```
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create));
        int inputDocumentPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
        int overlayDocumentPages = sReader.NumberOfPages;
        PdfContentByte background;            
        for (int i = 1; i <= inputDocumentPages; i++)
        {
            if (i <= overlayDocumentPages)
            {
                PdfImportedPage page = stamper.GetImportedPage(sReader, i);
                background = stamper.GetUnderContent(i);
                background.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
                background.Fill();
                background.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
                PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
                state.FillOpacity = 0.6f;
                state.BlendMode = PdfGState.BM_MULTIPLY;
                background.SetGState(state);
                background.SaveState();

            }
        }
        stamper.Close();
```

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you want to achieve. Fonts don't have a color in pdfs (unless you are talking about type 3 fonts)...

Comment: I want to change the color for new content. Please suggest.

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood you. In that case Paullo Muniz' answer shows you what to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
iTextSharp.text.Font fontNormalBlack = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, new BaseColor(Color.Blue));
iTextSharp.text.Font fontNormalBlue = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, new BaseColor(Color.Black));


Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);

string caminho = appPath + "//data//temp//" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf";
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(caminho, FileMode.Create));


doc.SetMargins(70, 70, 70, 70);
doc.AddCreationDate();
doc.Open();

Paragraph paragrafo = new Paragraph();


paragrafo.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
paragrafo.Add(new Chunk("Name: ", fontNormalBlack));
paragrafo.Add(new Chunk("Paulo Muniz" + "\n\n", fontNormalBlue));
paragrafo.Add(new Chunk("Birthday: ", fontNormalBlack));
paragrafo.Add(new Chunk("24/07" + "\n", fontNormalBlue));
doc.Add(paragrafo);


doc.Close();
```

Comment: Instead of `new BaseColor(Color.Blue)`, try `new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#0000ff"))`
Do the same with the black colour. Also, here is a good link that will help you navigate through it: https://csharpdoc.hotexamples.com/namespace/iTextSharp.text

Comment: or: `Color.FromArgb(0, 153, 255);`

Comment: I want to change the color for new content. Please suggest.

Comment: i tried this and not working.TextSharp.text.BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#0000ff"))

Comment: @svkrishna gavva what you tried doesn't look like what I've sent. If you are adding comments, please at least make sure you're copying the exact text. Also, did you check the link I've sent you above? What does it say?